# In Endgame, why didn't the Hulk's arm regenerate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-endgame

According to the comics, the Hulk has very fast regeneration abilities similar to Deadpool.

> At the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, the Hulk has his charred right arm in a cast because of the burns from using the Infinity Gauntlet to "unsnap" everyone who died at the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*.

Why hasn't it regenerated back yet, or even partially regenerated?

Comment: Presumably because of his finding a "third way" between brains and brawn. He's obviously dialled down his hulk powers.

Comment: There’s a theory, currently being studied by the finest minds of our generation, which posits that comics and movies are actually different.

Comment: Like @Valorum states, it seems safe to assume that if Bruce were to "Hulk out" and go fully savage Hulk then it's possible he could regenerate the arm. It seems possible that in this halfway state, his Hulk powers are not as intense.

Comment: @Kyza I've added [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212097/58193) below which quotes Joe Russo and is different to the accepted answer's speculation if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because that's not an ability that they've covered in the MCU. In the movies so far they've had The Hulk be basically invulnerable, in fact getting stronger as he soaks up hits in his standalone films, we haven't seen him do any healing at all on screen let alone at an accelerated rate. I understand that Endgame is already a long movie, ten more minutes run time to explain that The Hulk can regenerate, and oh that's always been a thing we just hadn't noticed was probably not a good idea.

Alternately the fact that the damage was done by the Infinity Stones may mean that he simply *can't* regenerate.

Comment: "I understand that Endgame is already a long movie, ten more minutes run time to explain that The Hulk can regenerate, and oh that's always been a thing we just hadn't noticed was probably not a good idea." The length isn't really relevant; randomly introducing a previously unheard of power - several movies after the character has been introduced - feels incredibly cheap to most viewers. Introducing Nebula's network to allow 2014-Thanos to know about the 2023-Avengers plans was bad enough.

Comment: “they've had The Hulk be basically invulnerable, in fact getting stronger as he soaks up hits in his standalone films” — he gets knocked out in Age of Ultron (by the Hulkbuster armour) and Infinity War (by Thanos), and is almost beaten by Thor in Ragnarok. He also seems to suffer against the Chitauri weapons in Avengers, and gets bitten by Fenris in Ragnarok. He’s not portrayed as invulnerable.

Comment: Banner also effectively commits suicide on Asgard and The Hulk emerges and he and Banner are both fine.  So they have, in fact, made it quite clear that The Hulk can repair damage quickly.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Did I say I was talking about Mark Ruffalo's Hulk? No I did not, I said Hulk's "standalone films" which none of those are.

Comment: @Ash: okay. It's just the question is about the Hulk in *Endgame*. Which is the same Hulk, continuity-wise, as the one played by Ed Norton in *The Incredible Hulk*, the only standalone movie to feature this Hulk.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite If we exclude _Hulk_ then you may have a point; I'm not 100% certain which film has the scene where he gets noticeably bigger, and angrier, every time he gets hit with a bullet.

Comment: @Ash: yup, *Hulk (2003)* is not part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think that's changed since last I checked, but that was years ago; I don't pay _that much_ attention to such things as a rule.

Comment: @Ash: a movie produced five years before the MCU was a thing *used* to be part of the MCU? Cool!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite There was a _carte blanche_ phase soon after _Iron Man_ came out where they were like "_all_ the movies with Marvel characters are canon" they removed a bunch (particularly the Spider-man series) pretty quickly but _Hulk_ wasn't one of them that got cut straight away.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had to downvote this because your main point about Hulk not having regenerative powers in the MCU just simply isn't correct. Again unfortunately your statement about it's because the damage was done by the Infinity Stones is actually the correct answer, see [my answer below](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212097/58193).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Where in the MCU is he shown to regenerate?

Comment: He spits out a bullet, breaks his neck and all but dies on the rainbow bridge and other things.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot But no actual healing occurs on screen, unless you can point at something I missed. Also Banner almost dying and Hulk taking over to save the day is not regeneration it's transformation.

Comment: Just because it’s inferred off screen doesn’t mean it doesn’t happen.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot But it does mean there's not an established healing mechanism shown within the films, he shrugs off what should be spectacular damage yes but without explanation.

Comment: Hulk regenerated in Incredible Hulk after Abomination stabbed him with the bone spike.

Answer (score 11):

## Because the damage was caused by the Infinity Gauntlet

Joe Russo has confirmed that the damage is "permanent" and compares it to the damage Thanos receives from using the Infinity Gauntlet. As such it is safe to assume the reason is because the damage came from the Infinity Gauntlet and so the Infinity Stones. The amount of power needed to unsnap, and in Thanos' case snap, is what caused such irreversible damage.

> “He’s lost an arm,” Russo says. “He lost Natasha. That’s not coming back. He’s damaged himself. I don’t know. It’s interesting. That’s permanent damage, the same way that it was permanent damage with Thanos. It’s irreversible damage. His arm, if you noticed, is a lot skinnier. It’s blackened. So, he loses a lot of strength there.”
>
> Russo does acknowledge that “permanent” means something different a world of magic and super science, but that’s not his concern any longer.
>
> “But who knows? There’s a lot of smart people left,” he says. “Maybe someone helps him repair that. Maybe someone gives him a new arm. I have no idea where that character goes from here. The nice thing is we didn’t have to pay attention to where it goes after this, we just try to tell a satisfying ending.”
>
> <sub>[Comicbook, Avengers: Endgame Director Reveals Hulk's Injury Is Permanent](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/05/07/avengers-endgame-hulk-injury-permanent-infinity-stones-joe-russo/)</sub>

Answer (score 10):

In the comics Professor Hulk has the benefit of Banner's brain but is no where near as strong as primitive Hulk. In fact when Professor Hulk gets to angry he reverts to “puny Banner” with Hulk's primitive mind.

Therefore this delay in healing does follow the comic book lore.

In addition this is an Infinity Gauntlet. Banner already states that it gives off tremendous radiation that will hurt him.

Comment: im not sure if I misheard but I believe Hulk says - "it's mostly gamma radiation, I should be fine" and "....I was made for this". He never mentions that it **will** hurt him

Comment: Sorry your right I re watched it since posting this. He does say it’s gamma radiation, but his “I should be fine” is not very definitive. Plus saying I should be fine could mean, I won’t die like you all will, as opposed to it won’t hurt me at all.

Answer (score 4):

1. MCU Hulk does not show deadpool levels of regeneration. While he does have regenerative capabilities they are nowhere as fast.
2. There's a very significant amount of damage that was inflicted. For reference:

   > Using the gauntlet straight up killed Tony. Hulk survived with merely a burnt arm.

That is already a huge testimony to his regenerative powers!

Comment: Also Tony only wished away Thanos army, Hulk has to wish back everything that was taken away and undo all the damage done to the planets remove all overgrown vegetation etc. that isn’t a lot more demanding then getting rid of half the universe.

Comment: True. Not sure if the "wish" affects how much damage the user takes, but even if it did, Tony got destroyed for a lot less than the Hulk had. That further goes on to show how much he can regenerate.

Answer (score 2):

Banner said in the *The Avengers* he shot himself in the head and Hulk spat the round out... seems like pretty good/quick healing to me so they just messed up.

> **Banner:** In case you needed to kill me, but you can't! I know! I tried! I got low. I didn't see an end, so I put a bullet in my mouth and the other guy spit it out!
>
> <sub>*The Avengers*</sub>

Comment: To me that line never implied any sort of healing or regeneration, only that he involuntarily transformed into the Hulk the instant the bullet hit.

Answer (score -1):

During the secret war ark, they had Banner Hulk - which is effectively Bruce Banners brain in Hulks body. Something we seem to be seeing in endgame. Professor Hulk is a combination of Savage hulks strength, Banners mind, and Grey Hulks cunning. Not the same thing. On top of this, Prof Hulk is actually consider the strongest hulk at a baseline level (disregarding the madder/stronger factor, which savage Hulk can utilize to his advantage due to being... well, savage). Or was, up until World war hulk, which seems to be simply the grey/savage combined.

Its all very confusing, but there are many Hulk's running around in the comics.One cannot simply assume something for the film; based on what they understand from the comics, because its not the same thing. Hulk heals because Prof Hulk has regenerated 90% of his body mass in comics doesn't quite work, because we don't even know what Hulk this is, let alone what his capabilities are. That being said, hopefully the arm Heals, and Hulk gets some actual fight time his next go around.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure given some of the wording here if you've written this as an answer to the question or as a reply to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211212/58193). You do have some good information here though so could you [edit] it to focus more on being a direct answer to the question if this was intended to be a reply to another answer?