# Was Hulk present at this event?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the end of *Avengers: Endgame*, was Hulk present at

> the funeral of Tony Stark?

I don't remember his fate.   Has he gone off somewhere in mourning for

> Natasha, effectively removing all of the original Avengers from active duty:   Stark and Natasha dead; Cap old and retired;   Clint being a family man; Thor (and Banner?) soul-searching?

Comment: Hopefully this is not just an obvious plot point which I didn't notice or have forgotten.

Comment: I don't really object to the edit, but its it really a spoiler that *someone's funeral* occurs in Endgame?

Comment: YEs, it is. Knowing that someone dies is a spoiler, even if you don't who.

Comment: @Brondahl - There are eight trillion deaths in the opening sequences.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - It seemed entirely obvious to me that they'd be killing off at least one (and potentially several) main characters

Comment: @Valorum Some folk still *hope* that no one dies at the end. Let's not **spoil** that for them.

Comment: @camden_kid - Anyone going into a movie called "endgame", expecting no-one to die is deluding themselves badly.

Comment: @Valorum So? Let them delude themselves and hope. No need to spoil it for them.

Comment: @camden_kid - I think you've misunderstood what a spoiler is.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

He was at the funeral, stood directly behind Thor.

[image]

Comment: The obvious follow-up question is: Who exactly is his tailor?

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer Yeah. Sharp suit, right? I suppose half the tailors in New York survived the snap, Hulk had enough time to open up a fast food shop and acquire a suitable wardrobe. New York does have plenty of very good tailors, though on the expensive side, but that's expected from an expensive city.

Comment: @Nomenator - Plus half the [enormous people](https://keyassets-p2.timeincuk.net/wp/prod/wp-content/uploads/sites/29/2016/10/resized-h_02590739-630x480.jpg) in [the world](https://viola.bz/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/0_a1b51_b47bc2e2_L.jpg) got zapped. All Hulk has to do is look them up, find out who's disappeared and raid their wardrobes.

Comment: Coming May 2020: "Avengers: Who The Hell Took My Suit? A Rando Undusting Story"

Answer (score 7):

He's there at the funeral with his arm in a sling, still recovering from using the gauntlet. See also [In Endgame, why didn't the Hulk's arm regenerate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211165/82909)

Comment: Alrighty then...