# Why does Professor Hulk wear glasses?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-endgame

Professor Hulk is featured in *Avengers: Endgame* predominantly wearing glasses

> (other than when he poses for pictures with fans and is impersonating Hulk in the Battle of New York).

But why does he need glasses? Are we saying that Hulk has always been visually impaired?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211165/58193).

Comment: Bruce (not Hulk) wears glasses. Why would it be odd for a hybrid of Bruce and the Hulk to wear glasses?

Comment: Has Hulk ever demonstrated *not* being nearsighted? It seems very fitting with his actions. He usually attacks things close to him and doesn't usually demonstrate great aim or situational awareness of things far away.

Comment: _HULK HATE PUT FINGERS IN EYES_

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looking at the image below of Professor Hulk in Endgame, the strength of his glasses is very low, as there is no visible displacement of his temple as seen through the lenses. This means that (a) the glasses are purely ornamental, meant to provide a less frightening countenance, or (b) they are very low-strength reading glasses. The fact that he doesn't need the glasses for most things is evidenced from the funeral picture in the answer by TheLethalCarrot, where he doesn't wear them. My guess is that (a) is the right answer; with the history of violent Hulk, Banner would take steps to create a different, more intellectual image.

[image]

Comment: At the funeral he could be wearing contact lenses

Comment: True, but why then not wear them all the time?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen You could ask that about regular people who sometimes wear glasses and sometimes don't. There are plenty of good reasons. In this case it might be personal preference. It's not unusual, so I'm not sure why you're asking.

Comment: I suspect that (a) is also for reminding himself, to help him keep his two aspects in balance.

Answer (score 9):

In *Avengers: Endgame* after the time skip Professor Hulk explains to those that meet him in the cafe that he merged Banner and Hulk together to get the best of both, Banner's intellect and Hulk's strength and powers. One of these powers is super healing as we see in *Thor: Ragnarok* when Banner jumps onto the Rainbow Bridge and is all but killed in the process until Hulk comes out and they are both fine again.

However, in *Avengers: Endgame* we see that Professor Hulk is damaged by perfoming

> the reverse snap

and is still seen to be damaged by it at the end of the movie.

[image: Professor Hulk at Stark's funeral with his arm in a sling]

Ignoring that this might have been because it was the

> Infinity Stones

that damaged him so badly it could also have been down to his regenerative powers not being as strong as they once were. As such Banner's bad eyesight could have transferred into Professor Hulk and with his regenerative powers at a lower level than they once were he could no longer repair this. Therefore, he now needs to wear glasses.

Comment: I thought he looked less damaged later in the movie than immediately after the snap.  So his healing is kicking in, just at a slower than normal rate because of the source of the damage.

Answer (score 0):

He needs glasses due to the fact that his consciousness is that of Bruce Banner's. Bruce Banner is visually impaired, therefore the Hulk is.

Comment: Visual impairment comes in two main types: Cerebral (issue with the brain's processing of signal from the eyes) and Ocular (physical issue with the eyes). We don't know which one Bruce or the Hulk has, but Ocular is *way* *way* more common. So unless you have some evidence that Bruce Banner's issue is CVI rather than OVI, this argument doesn't make sense.